Basic question about lambda code that extracts info from a page using node.js 20
I'm learning how to use AWS lambda with node js 18-20, but I'm having a hard time getting even the most basic examples to work. For example, I have the sparticuz/chromium 109.0.5 module and puppeteer-core 19.4.0, and I can't get this example to work on node js 20:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");

async function handler(event = {}, context = {}) {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
      headless: chromium.headless,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      args: [...chromium.args, "--hide-scrollbars", "--disable-web-security"],
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Navegar a la página de ejemplo (example.com) con manejo de errores y reintento
    let success = false;
    let attempts = 0;
    while (!success && attempts < 3) {
      try {
        await page.goto("https://example.com", { timeout: 30000 }); // Ajusta el tiempo de espera según sea necesario
        success = true;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error al navegar a la página:", err);
        attempts++;
      }
    }

    // Verificar si la navegación fue exitosa
    if (!success) {
      console.error("La navegación no pudo completarse después de varios intentos.");
      await browser.close();
      return;
    }

    // Extraer el título de la página y mostrarlo en la consola
    const title = await page.title();
    console.log("Título de la página:", title);

    // Extraer el contenido de la página y mostrarlo en la consola
    const content = await page.content();
    console.log("Contenido de la página:", content);

    // Cerrar el navegador
    await browser.close();
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Ocurrió un error:", err);
  }
}

module.exports = { handler };


The code must open a chromium instance, navigate to example.com page and extract the title and content of the page, to finally display them in the console and close the browser.
But instead the following happens:
START RequestId: 56f8d3b6-df34-4116-ac86-8d9867dac522 Version: $LATEST
2024-04-30T19:21:24.738Z    56f8d3b6-df34-4116-ac86-8d9867dac522    INFO    Ocurrió un error: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:299:20)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:287:24)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:527:10)
    at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:253:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
END RequestId: 56f8d3b6-df34-4116-ac86-8d9867dac522
REPORT RequestId: 56f8d3b6-df34-4116-ac86-8d9867dac522  Duration: 3292.73 ms    Billed Duration: 3293 ms    Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 406 MB Init Duration: 365.70 ms

The project structure is:
project.zip
├── node_modules/        
├── package.json         
├── package-lock.json   
└── index.js  

The lambda function config to replicate the error is the following:
Runtime: node.js 20
Architecture: x86_64
I don't know if the error will have to do with the version of the dependencies, the different structure of the project from those used in node js 14-16, or simply some wrong parameter or configuration within the code that I am overlooking. Thanks in advance!

Looks like it's missing a dependency, based on the error message. Relevant A on a related Q. Also interesting you're being charged for 4x the time it took to run.
